# ViewFlipper Image Hyperlink

Tags: android, imageview, viewflipper

In Android Studio, I've succeeded in making a viewFlipper flick through about 10 images.

Is it possible to give each image a unique hyperlink so that when the user clicks on the image, they are directed to a unique website?

I've followed multiple tutorials online, but I keep coming across a null pointer exception error.

Comment: You need to post some relevant code and stacktrace for the error you are getting.

Comment: I'm not looking for help on fixing errors, I'm looking for help in how to do it correctly. I'm choosing to start fresh, looking for help in acquiring the skills to do it.